# Wakanda studio enters infinite loop when "file not found" error displayed

Tags: infinite-loop, wakanda

I have installed Wakanda Studio  11 build 11.195328 (and server) on my Macbook Pro/OSX El Capitan.

When i open the "School management" solution and try to display the `onGet` event code for a calculated attribute, i get an error window showing a message like:

> The `model.TimeTable.rec_type.onGet` was not found

Clicking on the "OK" button does not close the window and I need to "Force Quit" Wakanda Studio to reopen it.

I think this is a bug, but i also would like to know if existing solutions need to be "migrated" to be compatible with the newest version of Wakanda.

Answer (score 0):

I tested with School Management Solution and got the same error message when clicking the "+" icon next to rec_type attribute of Timetable class in model designer. But, I was able to close the dialog by clicking "OK". It did not go into infinite-loop.

School Management was written in WAK7 and it is compatible with Wakanda 11.195328. Meaning you can still deploy and run it in Wakanda studio and serve. The model API and structure however, have become deprecated. A brief introduction of model API and syntax can be found [here](http://livedoc.wakanda.org/Model/Working-with-the-Model-API.200-995188.en.html).

School management is still fully functional in Wakanda 11. The only thing you need to do is add three users named: 'administrator', 'teacher', 'student' in Directory since the old directory is not supported anymore.

If you would like to continue development on School Management or solutions created from earlier versions, they will need to be migrated.

Comment: I will add the three users and test it in WAK11. Any idea about the infinite loop? I have the same problem with other soutions.